Invariance test for a longitudinal multi-group growth model. Is a group invariance test for all timepoints required?
I have data from 7 waves for a construct that includes samples from two different countries. As a preliminary step for a growth curve analysis, a longitudinal invariance test has already been conducted and supports partial strong invariance. My question is,  Is there a need to run a group invariance test for all the time points I have? I am planning to specify the country variable as a time-invariant covariate in my growth curve model.
Additionally, if there is literature on how many items need to remain "un-freed" for invariance to hold, that would be very helpful.
Thank you all for your support


Is there a need to run a group invariance test for all the time points I have?

If you plan to make comparisons of any parameter(s) across those groups, then measurement invariance is an assumption underlying any test of such a comparison.

how many items need to remain "un-freed" for invariance to hold

Technically, only 1 invariant item is needed, but you would have to be lucky in guessing which it is, because constraining only 1 indicator to equality is equivalent to any configurally invariant model.  Testing partial invariance is only possible with at least 2 "anchor items".
http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.1086/209528
https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-018-1151-3

Thank you so much for your advice, Terrence! I am currently tryiing to figure out a good way to execute this. Thank you again for the confirmation.
